# What is this long error in React from material ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Compiled with problems:X

ERROR in ./src/Pages/Crypto_transactions.js 184:35-43

export 'default' (imported as 'DataGrid') was not found in '@material-ui/data-grid' (possible exports: DATA_GRID_PROPTYPES, DEFAULT_GRID_COL_TYPE_KEY, DEFAULT_GRID_OPTIONS, DEFAULT_GRID_PROPS_FROM_OPTIONS, DEFAULT_GRID_SLOTS_COMPONENTS, DataGrid, GRID_BOOLEAN_COLUMN_TYPE, GRID_CELL_CSS_CLASS, GRID_CELL_CSS_CLASS_SUFFIX, GRID_COLUMN_HEADER_CSS_CLASS, GRID_COLUMN_HEADER_CSS_CLASS_SUFFIX, GRID_COLUMN_HEADER_DRAGGING_CSS_CLASS, GRID_COLUMN_HEADER_DROP_ZONE_CSS_CLASS, GRID_COLUMN_HEADER_SEPARATOR_RESIZABLE_CSS_CLASS, GRID_COLUMN_HEADER_TITLE_CSS_CLASS, GRID_CSS_CLASS_PREFIX, GRID_DATETIME_COLUMN_TYPE, GRID_DATETIME_COL_DEF, GRID_DATE_COLUMN_TYPE, GRID_DATE_COL_DEF, GRID_DEFAULT_LOCALE_TEXT, GRID_EXPERIMENTAL_ENABLED, GRID_NUMBER_COLUMN_TYPE, GRID_NUMERIC_COL_DEF, GRID_ROOT_CSS_CLASS_SUFFIX, GRID_ROW_CSS_CLASS, GRID_ROW_CSS_CLASS_SUFFIX, GRID_STRING_COLUMN_TYPE, GRID_STRING_COL_DEF, GridAddIcon, GridApiContext, GridArrowDownwardIcon, GridArrowUpwardIcon, GridAutoSizer, GridBody, GridCell, GridCellCheckboxForwardRef, GridCellCheckboxRenderer, GridCheckCircleIcon, GridCheckIcon, GridCloseIcon, GridColumnHeaderItem, GridColumnHeaderMenu, GridColumnHeaderSeparator, GridColumnHeaderSortIcon, GridColumnHeaderTitle, GridColumnHeadersItemCollection, GridColumnIcon, GridColumnMenu, GridColumnMenuContainer, GridColumnsContainer, GridColumnsHeader, GridColumnsMenuItem, GridColumnsPanel, GridDataContainer, GridDensityTypes, GridDragIcon, GridEditInputCell, GridEditSingleSelectCell, GridEmptyCell, GridErrorHandler, GridEvents, GridFeatureModeConstant, GridFilterAltIcon, GridFilterForm, GridFilterInputValue, GridFilterListIcon, GridFilterMenuItem, GridFilterPanel, GridFooter, GridFooterContainer, GridFooterPlaceholder, GridHeader, GridHeaderCheckbox, GridHeaderPlaceholder, GridLinkOperator, GridLoadIcon, GridLoadingOverlay, GridMenu, GridMenuIcon, GridNoRowsOverlay, GridOverlay, GridOverlays, GridPagination, GridPanel, GridPanelContent, GridPanelFooter, GridPanelHeader, GridPanelWrapper, GridPreferencePanelsValue, GridPreferencesPanel, GridRenderingZone, GridRoot, GridRow, GridRowCells, GridRowCount, GridSaveAltIcon, GridScrollArea, GridSearchIcon, GridSelectedRowCount, GridSeparatorIcon, GridStickyContainer, GridTableRowsIcon, GridToolbar, GridToolbarColumnsButton, GridToolbarContainer, GridToolbarDensitySelector, GridToolbarExport, GridToolbarFilterButton, GridTripleDotsVerticalIcon, GridViewHeadlineIcon, GridViewStreamIcon, GridViewport, GridWindow, HideGridColMenuItem, MAX_PAGE_SIZE, SUBMIT_FILTER_STROKE_TIME, Signature, SortGridMenuItems, activeGridFilterItemsSelector, allGridColumnsFieldsSelector, allGridColumnsSelector, arSD, bgBG, checkGridRowIdIsValid, convertGridRowsPropToState, csCZ, deDE, elGR, enUS, esES, filterGridColumnLookupSelector, filterGridItemsCounterSelector, filterGridStateSelector, filterableGridColumnsIdsSelector, filterableGridColumnsSelector, frFR, getGridColDef, getGridDateOperators, getGridDefaultColumnTypes, getGridNumericColumnOperators, getGridStringOperators, getInitialGridColumnReorderState, getInitialGridColumnResizeState, getInitialGridColumnsState, getInitialGridFilterState, getInitialGridRenderingState, getInitialGridRowState, getInitialGridSortingState, getInitialGridState, getInitialVisibleGridRowsState, gridCheckboxSelectionColDef, gridColumnLookupSelector, gridColumnMenuStateSelector, gridColumnReorderDragColSelector, gridColumnReorderSelector, gridColumnResizeSelector, gridColumnsMetaSelector, gridColumnsSelector, gridColumnsTotalWidthSelector, gridDateFormatter, gridDateTimeFormatter, gridEditRowsStateSelector, gridFocusCellSelector, gridFocusColumnHeaderSelector, gridFocusStateSelector, gridPaginatedVisibleSortedGridRowIdsSelector, gridPaginationSelector, gridPanelClasses, gridPreferencePanelStateSelector, gridResizingColumnFieldSelector, gridRowCountSelector, gridRowsLookupSelector, gridRowsStateSelector, gridScrollbarStateSelector, gridSelectionStateSelector, gridSortColumnLookupSelector, gridSortModelSelector, gridTabIndexCellSelector, gridTabIndexColumnHeaderSelector, gridTabIndexStateSelector, gridViewportSizeStateSelector, itIT, jaJP, nlNL, plPL, plPLGrid, ptBR, renderEditInputCell, renderEditSingleSelectCell, ruRU, ruRUGrid, selectedGridRowsCountSelector, selectedGridRowsSelector, selectedIdsLookupSelector, skSK, skSKGrid, sortedGridRowIdsSelector, sortedGridRowsSelector, trTR, ukUA, ukUAGrid, unorderedGridRowIdsSelector, unorderedGridRowModelsSelector, useApi, useDataGridComponent, useGridApi, useGridApiEventHandler, useGridApiMethod, useGridApiOptionHandler, useGridApiRef, useGridColumnMenu, useGridColumnReorder, useGridColumnResize, useGridColumns, useGridComponents, useGridContainerProps, useGridControlState, useGridEditRows, useGridFilter, useGridFocus, useGridKeyboard, useGridKeyboardNavigation, useGridPage, useGridPageSize, useGridParamsApi, useGridPreferencesPanel, useGridReducer, useGridRows, useGridScrollFn, useGridSelection, useGridSelector, useGridSlotComponentProps, useGridSorting, useGridState, useGridVirtualRows, useLogger, useLoggerFactory, useNativeEventListener, visibleGridColumnsLengthSelector, visibleGridColumnsSelector, visibleGridRowCountSelector, visibleGridRowsStateSelector, visibleSortedGridRowIdsSelector, visibleSortedGridRowsAsArraySelector, visibleSortedGridRowsSelector)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `import DataGrid from '@material-ui/data-grid'`, which doesn't have a `default` export.

You probably want

```
import { DataGrid } from '@material-ui/data-grid'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `import {DataGrid} from "@mui/material";` instead of `import DataGrid from "@mui/material";`. It will solve the problem.

When It wants to import a named component, It must be included inside curly braces. `{DataGrid}` instead of `DataGrid`.

A Component with braces specifies a particular element of the React package. Without braces it will import default react package.